# What items can I disenchant with an Enchanting skill of 450?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a level 65 tradeskill alt who has maxed out his Enchanting at 450. Will he be able to disenchant *any* Cataclysm-level bind-on-equip items I come across on my level 85 main, or are there some higher-level items which he won't be able to dispose of unless I level him up to 75 to unlock the next tier of Enchanting skill (450-525)?

Comment: Bonus points for any answer that includes a complete breakdown of what item levels can be disenchanted at each tier of Enchanting, since I couldn't find a complete list myself.

Comment: Bonus points? SCORE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enchanting skill of 450 will allow you to disenchant greens up to ilvl 333, and blues up to ilvl 346.

So yeah, you can disenchant some Cataclysm level items, but not max level stuff.

For additional info, see [Disenchanting](http://www.wowpedia.org/Disenchanting) and [Disenchanting Tables](http://www.wowpedia.org/Disenchanting_tables) at WoWPedia.